# Autocomplete box will not populate from the database

Tags: php, sql

So I tried setting up my autocomplete box through codeignighter framework and I cannot seem to get the textbox to populate the results from the  database.

This is my Model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class nextCreateCampaign_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
     parent::__construct();
     // Your own constructor code           
}

function getUser($term)
{

$sql = $this->db->query('select campaign_name, remote_service_ID from ad_report_new.service where remote_service_ID like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($term) .'%" order by remote_service_ID');

return $sql ->result();
}
}
?>
```

This is my Controller campaign.php

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Campaign extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/campaign
 *  - or -  
 *      http://example.com/index.php/campaign/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/campaign/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */


function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('nextCreateCampaign_model');
}
public function index(){
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('nextCreateCampaign');
}

public function getUserEmail()
{


if ( !isset($_GET['term']) )
exit;
$term = $_REQUEST['term'];
    $data = array();
    $rows = $this->nextCreateCampaign_model->getUser($term);
        foreach( $rows as $row )
        {
            $data[] = array(
                'label' => $row->remote_service_ID.', '. $row->email,
                'value' => $row->remote_service_ID);   // here i am taking name as value     so it will display name in text field, you can change it as per your choice.
        }
     echo json_encode($data);
     flush();

}


}

/* End of file campaign.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/campaign.php */
```

And finally my view

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Create/Edit Pay For Performance Campaigns</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css" />




<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
  function split( val ) {
            return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
            function extractLast( term ) {
             return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#txtinput" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
          .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/campaign/getUserEmail",{
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                },response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 1 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( "," );
                return false;
            }
        });

 });

</script>


</head>

<style>
#txtinput{width:400px;height: 30px;border-radius:8px;border:1px solid #999;}

</style>

<body>
<input type="text" id="txtinput" size="20" />
</body>
```

Comment: Try adding exit after  echo json_encode($data);

Comment: @KutePHP When I added exit the page doesn't load...it's just blank. the source is blank also